# Get class with custom attribute where customproperty has certain value

Tags: c#, reflection

I have implemented a Attribute-Class which looks like:

```
internal class DataExchangeItem : Attribute
{
   public DataExchangeItem(string request)
   {
      Request = request;
   }

   public string Request { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have several classes where I use this attribute like:

```
[DataExchangeItem("DownloadDataRequest")]
internal class DownloadDataRequestHandler : IDataHandler
{ ... }
```

Than I have a class with one static method which looks like

```
public static Class RequestHandlerCreator
{
   public static IDataHandler CreateDataHandler(string request)
   {
      switch(request){... // compare strings and give DataHandler}
   }
}
```

Now I'm trying to replace the switch-statement with a statement, where I can check the attributes of all classes and then get the class which has my searched request-string in the attribute-Request-property.

To get a List of all `Type`s where my attribute is defined I use:

```
List<Type> customAttributes = (from type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                                    where type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataExchangeItem),true).Length > 0
                                    where type.GetCustomAttributesData().Count > 0
                                    select type).ToList();
```

I know that I can call `type.GetCustomAttributesData()` on a `Type`-`Object` to get a List of `CustomAttributeData`. Each `CustomAttributeData`-Property than has a collection of NamedArguments.

Unfortunately I don't manage it to get the `Type`-Object for my searched string.

My question now is:

> How can I get the Type in a assembly where my custom-attribute is
>   defined and the Request-Property has my searched value?

---

Thanks The Dutch Man. Your code works. I transformed it completely in a linq-statement:

```
 private static Type FindTypeForRequest(string request)
        {
            return (from module in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Modules 
                    where module.GetTypes().Length > 0 
                    from type in module.GetTypes() 
                    where type.CustomAttributes.Any() 
                    let customAttribute = type.CustomAttributes.SingleOrDefault(a => a.AttributeType == typeof (DataExchangeItem)) 
                    where customAttribute != null 
                    where customAttribute.ConstructorArguments.Any(argument => argument.Value.ToString() == request) 
                    select type).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, do you want the get the type from DownloadDataRequest? Or the type of the method/class that holds the attributes?

Comment: I want the Type of DownloadDataRequestHandler if I RequestHandlerCreator.CreateDataHandler("DownloadDataRequest")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this is how I would do it:

```
 public Type CreateDataHandler(string requestName)
    {
        Assembly _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        foreach (Module _module in _assembly.Modules)
        {
            if (_module.GetTypes().Length > 0)
            {
                foreach(Type _type in _module.GetTypes())
                {
                    if (_type.CustomAttributes.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        CustomAttributeData _customAttribute = _type.CustomAttributes.SingleOrDefault(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(DataExchangeItem));
                        if (_customAttribute != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var _argument in _customAttribute.ConstructorArguments)
                            {
                                if (_argument.Value.ToString() == requestName)
                                {
                                    return _type;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Let me know if this works out.